# Android Market Question

Tags: android, google-play

Recently I published my new application, this application is showing in my Android device, however when I go to my Android Market Home, the app is not there. I am wondering if there is something I can do to fix this because I'll be making an update soon.

Comment: It might take a bit to appear in the Market, when did you submit the app?

Comment: I submitted it yesterday morning

Comment: @user739375 you should go to https://market.android.com/publish/Home and check if the application status says "Published"

Comment: No the problem is, the application is not even showing on market.android.com/publish/Home but it is showing on my Android phone

Comment: @user739375 try uploading it again then :)

Comment: I already did, it says there's already the same package name. I know I published my application because it is showing on my Android Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange, maybe this can help http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=2d57cbb5ca036b75&hl=en

Comment: I solved the problem thanks, I used https://market.android.com/publish/Home#AppEditorPlace:p=<PACKAGE NAME>, although it is invincible, I am still able to update it . Thanks!